# An Ideal in the Group Ring $RG$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

So I'm working on Abstract Algrebra (Dummit & Foote).

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity $1$ and let $G=\{g_1, ..., g_n\}$ be a finite group. Prove that $$I=\{\sum_{i=1}^n ag_i | a\in R\},$$ i.e. the $R$-multiples of the element $g_1+...+g_n$, is an ideal in the group ring $RG$.

On the one hand,

$(1).$ $I$ is non-empty since $$g_1+...+g_n=\sum_{i=1}^n 1g_i\in I.$$

$(2).$ $I$ is closed under subtraction since $$\sum_{i=1}^n ag_i-\sum_{i=1}^n bg_i=\sum_{i=1}^n (a-b)g_i.$$

$(3).$ $I$ is closed under multiplication by all the elements in $RG$, so we need to prove that $$(\sum_{i=1}^n b_ig_i)\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^n ag_i)=\sum_{k=1}^n(\sum_{g_ig_j=g_k} ab_j)g_k\in RG.$$ How can one show that $$\sum_{g_ig_j=g_k} ab_j=\sum_{g_ig_j=g_s} ab_j$$ for any $1\leq k,s\leq n$?

Alternatively, $I$ must be the kernel of some ring homomorphism. It seems to be trivial but I just cannot find it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: It is enough to show that it is closed under multiplication by elements from the group. And these permute the summands in the element generating the ideal.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you! So given $g_i\in G$, we know that $g_{i}g_{1}, ..., g_{i}g_{n}$ is a permutation of $g_1, ..., g_n$, and the same result holds for right multiplication, since the left and right cancellation laws hold in $G$. Now if $\sum_{i=1}^n ag_i \in I$, then $g_k(\sum_{i=1}^n ag_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n a(g_kg_i)=\sum_{j=1}^n ag_j \in I$. Likewise, $I$ is closed under right multiplication by all the group elements.

Comment: Therefore if $\sum_{i=1}^n b_ig_i \in RG$, we obtain that $$(\sum_{i=1}^n b_ig_i)(\sum_{j=1}^n ag_j)=(\sum_{i=1}^n (ab_i)g_i)(\sum_{j=1}^n g_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n(ab_i)(g_ig_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n(ab_i)g_k=\sum_{k=1}^n \Big( a\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \Big)g_k\in I.$$ Likewise, $I$ is closed under right multiplication by all the elements in $RG$. Hence $I$ is an ideal of $RG$. Is that correct? :-)